# CSS grid items are not ordered according to grid-area property

Tags: css, css-grid

I have this simple grid

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(6, 1fr) / repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "hd  hd  hd  hd  hd  hd  hd  hd  hd  hd  hd  hd"
    "nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav"
    "mn  mn  mn  mn  mn  mn  mn  mn  mn  mn  mn  mn"
    "sb  sb  sb  sb  sb  sb  sb  sb  sb  sb  sb  sb"
    "adv adv adv adv adv adv adv adv adv adv adv adv"
    "ft  ft  ft  ft  ft  ft  ft  ft  ft  ft  ft  ft";
   gap: 1em;
 }
 
#header {
  grid-area: "hd";
}

#nav {
  grid-area: "nav";
}

#main {
  grid-area: "mn";
}

#aside {
  grid-area: "sb";
}

#adv {
  grid-area: "adv";
}

#footer {
  grid-area: "ft";
}

.wrapper > * {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header id="header">Header</header>
  <nav id="nav">Nav</nav>
  <aside id="aside">Sidebar</aside>
  <main id="main">Main</main>
  <div id="adv">advertising</div>
  <footer id="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make each element take up the whole row using the grid-area notation, but it's **showing all items on the same row**

I know I can use `grid-column: span 12;` but I want a unified style of code in my code base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw two things that when fixed made it work for me:

1. You should not use quotation marks for the inner ids/classes:

   `#header {
       grid-area: hd;
   }`
2. You missed one hd (It says h instead of hd) in the top row in the grid-template-areas key.

Comment: the hd error is just a copy paste error on my side, but removing the double quotations solved it for me! thanx for that!